# How generate hyperlinks for news show in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i created a  news panel where we use this code for displaying news :

```
 <marquee direction="up" >

<?php 
$query = $this->db->get('news');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->news;
    echo $row->urladdress;

    echo '<br/>';
}
?>

</marquee>
```

where it show correct , all data get fetched and run marquee good ,

but we tried ,when we click on news then it go urladdress , which fetch from table . By using this code but not work -

```
<marquee direction="up" >
               <?php 
               $query = $this->db->get('student');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->news;
    echo $row->urladdress;
    echo '<a href="$row->urladdress">click here</a>';
    echo '<br/>';
}
 </marquee>
```

Comment: `<a href'` is url ofcourse it goes to some url, what is the problem in it ?

Comment: but $row->urladdress not print the url from table , so it give error??

Comment: You can construct your anchor tag in codeigniter way ! (as @Saty suggests)

Comment: @princekumar  I think the problem is querying the wrong table.There is no row called url in the students table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<marquee direction="up" >
<?php
    $query = $this->db->get('student');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        echo $row->news;
        echo $row->urladdress;
        echo '<a href="'.$row['urladdress'].'">click here</a>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Read [CI anchor](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
echo anchor($row->urladdress, 'click here', 'title="click here"');
```

Comment: @princekumar i am providing the solution based on  codeigniter standered

Answer (score 1):

its `""` not `''` to echo value of field

```
echo "<a href='$row->urladdress'>click here</a>";
```

OR

```
echo '<a href="'.$row->urladdress.'">click here</a>';
```

Comment: i saw ur comment to @saty answer but still thought u should know what was real problem.By the way saty's answer is good one.